# Change view upon google sign in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I've added Google sign in to my app which is working but I can't seem to get my view to change upon a successful sign in programmatically.

This is my demo story board. The grey box being the sign in button, I've added a button "move page manually" with a segue from the login screen to the tab bar controller screen. Clicking this works as expected, I need the same to happen automatically when the app detects the user is signed in.

When the user opens the app the first screen is a view controller "login screen" if the user is logged in checked by the below code I want to forward them to the home screen (first tab). Please let me know if there's a better/faster way of doing this instead if possible.

[image: Storyboard]

Loginscreen :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Google sign in
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    // Check if they're already signed in
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

    // check if the user is signed in
    if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()){
        print("signed in")
        // Forward the user here straight away...
    } else {
        print ("not signed in")
        // Need to handle the forwarding once they sign in.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add a `Segue` from your login screen to whichever `ViewController` you want and write your code like so:

```
if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()){
        print("signed in")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("your_segue_name", sender: self)
        // Forward the user here straight away...
    }
```

Or you can present the `ViewController` modally by:

```
if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()){
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Yourstoryboardname(Example: Main)", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourviewcontrollertobepresented") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You need to **NAME** your viewcontroller which you want to be present. To do that, you click on your `ViewController` in storyboard and in the `Identity inspector` you'll find `Storyboard ID`. Name it what you want and give the same name in `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourviewcontrollertobepresented")`

Comment: Great thanks, the second option worked! Although I had to put it in a notification listener as each time google tries the sign in it takes a second or two which was causing the page to switch before the users email had been retrieved causing failures. I'm not sure what the recommended way of speeding up Google sign in is, maybe cache the details once the user has logged in.